# ColdFusion 2018 with bundled tomcat vs ColdFusion 2018 on Native Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion

Legend:

1. Native tomcat CF = CF installed on native tomcat or tomcat which was
   already installed on your system.
2. Bundled tomcat CF = Default CF
   installation.

I have experience working with bundled tomcat CF. Today I tried using Native tomcat CF.

The only difference i could find is that - 
With native tomcat CF, you deploy your CF app in **coldfusion instance** you have created by war file and with bunlded tomcat CF, you deploy your CF app in **wwwroot** folder.

I tried to find out difference online but with no luck.

From this [Charlie's presentation](http://www.carehart.org/presentations/cf10_on_tomcat.pdf), On page 20, I came to know about that with Native tomcat, we lose some CGI variables, CF Session Replications, multiple webroot support and SES URL support. But this article was written for CF10. Is this remain true for CF 2018?

I would like to know which one we should use native tomcat CF or bundled tomcat CF and what are the advantages/ disadvantages of using one over another?

Comment: The bundled Tomcat version has been specifically configured and tuned to work with ColdFusion by the Adobe team. That is why it has those additional pieces of information that we are used to having available to us when working with ColdFusion. Why do you want to use native Tomcat instead? What is missing for you in the bundled version?

Comment: @Miguel-F, Nothing is missing. I was just trying out the option and wanted to know more about it, that's it.